# Jsoup: "Which span does this element belong to?"

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Assuming I have found an element using:

```
Element link = div.select("a:not([class])").first();
```

I now want to find out whether this *particular* element is enclosed within a `<span class="uniqspan">` -- not necessarily a direct descendant.

Is there a way to do that in Jsoup?

Update: I just found the wonderful `Element.parent()`. I am going to check whether this can be a start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not directly possible from the `Element link` on. I'd suggest to collect all links in a `span.uniqspan` first and then check if it [contains](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) the `link`.

E.g.

```
Element link = div.select("a:not([class])").first();
Elements linksInUniqspan = document.select("span.uniqspan a:not([class])");

if (linksInUniqspan.contains(link)) {
    // Link is inside span.uniqspan.
} else {
    // Link is not inside span.uniqspan.
}
```

Comment: That's an excellent solution. What do you think of `if ((link.parent().tagName().equals("span")) && (link.parent().className().equals("uniqspan")))`?

Comment: You can do so. But this only checks the direct parent and won't work when it is one level up or something. You would need to check each parent in a loop.